Why won't blender hold the keyframe?
How do you get things to move to the next point and NOT take the end point into consideration?
I have a hand. The hand starts on the counter, moves to the face, then moves to the side of the head, then taps a finger on the side of the head 3 times, then moves to the back pocket.
Blender is so fixated on its end point that it skips details. It just washes out the taping on the head to stream line right to the back pocket.
Same with the camera. The camera needs to be in place X and then glide to place Y and then glide to place Z and stay there.
But again, Blender is so fixated on the last placement that it starts moving to the end point and skips all the keyframe stops in between.
I set the keyframe for the entire rig each time to make sure I don't forget anything. I tap A so it selects everything then I keyframe it.
I Keyframe it for location, rotation, scale and custom properties.
How do I make it glide to the next point and not disregard everything between the starting and end keyframes?
EXAMPLE: https://youtu.be/gv-a3-xnI9U

You did not put key frames for the rest of her arm while she’s tapping her head, only for her finger. Each bone in an armature, indeed every animatable property in Blender, only respects its own keyframes.

To fix the animation, duplicate the key frames for the arm bones at frame 12, and move the duplicate to the last time the arm should still be in the head position (somewhere around frame 23). I strongly recommend you take a look at the Graph editor with the finger and arm bones selected, as this will give you a visualization of the properties changing across key frames. You should also pay attention to the channel names at the left of the Dope Sheet editor (cropped out of the video for some reason).

I keyframed the entire armature. I do that every time. I don't just keyframe what I moved because I'm afraid I'll forget something. I moved her hand to tap and I pressed A to select the entire armature and then keyframed it. Then repeated it.
That's why it works when you remove the last keyframe.

Only on frames 1 and 10, though. All the other places, you did something less. See marked screenshot.
